# Github Projects Nodejs Web Api

Tags: mysql, node.js, github, sequelize.js

at the moment I'm trying to get into *node.js*, especially as a web-api with dedicated functions of getting informations from a database.

I use *Sequelize* on a MySQL-Database, with *Sequelize-auto*. The database I am using is the example database *Sakila*. For the web service I will use *Express*.

I would like to know, if somebody knows *good*, *well-structured* GitHub-Projects, that use the same or at least almost the same technologies I mentioned and that I can use as a reference.

Best regards and thanks, Anton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize have an example project

https://github.com/sequelize/express-example